# How to add shadows in Game Environment

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't able to get shadows within my 3d environment setup for the scene. As per my understanding, I have checked all settings but can't able to get success.

Here you have a sample scene example without any shadows displayed:

[image]

I have set my light component and lighting settings:

[image]

Car chassis material inspector:

[image]

So please give me guidance so I can get shadows of each environment objects in gameplay.

Comment: how do the material settings look for your scene objects? do you use static lightning?

Comment: I have updated my question with car chassis material property and as like this other object's material has the same kind of property. No I have used real-time lighting only

Comment: Did you configure lighting and baked/rendered the lighting? see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GlobalIllumination.html

Comment: I have updated my question with one reference image updated...

Comment: Can you show us some of the details for the materials for the car and the environment? Seeing the shaders would be a huge help

Comment: Now I can't able to upload more images over above: 1) car body material, I have updated - https://drive.google.com/open?id=146qkjEt9uSwQmijpxVDNVbAUgNGNSmnW 2) environment all objects have similar kind of material assigned - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cVW07Uz4MD8C-5O3Z3EQ2VbJKpmRDc92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Quality Settings, Shadows was disabled by default. I enabled that and its start showing shadows in the game environment.

[image]